# Content security policy error for android-image selection in ember-cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, ember.js, ember-cli

in my ember-cordova app, am getting following error, while adding image from android devise

```
Refused to load the image 'content://media/external/images/media/609' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: https://res.cloudinary.com content://media/external/images".
```

I have following in config/environment file:

```
contentSecurityPolicy: {
  "img-src": "'self' data: https://res.cloudinary.com",
  "style-src": "'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com",
  "font-src": "'self' data: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com"
},
```

I tried with adding `content://media/external/images/` in above block, but still facing error. I might not be adding it properly.
Can anyone please help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your config.xml here.

Comment: `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.0.1" />` Using these plugins for camera support and uploading files

Comment: Does adding "content:" to your `img-src` fix the problem? I haven't tried this out, which is why I'm dropping this in a comment instead of an answer :)

Comment: Thanks @oreoshake , but will ta accept both "data: content:" in img-src? as i tried adding both and that was giving me syntax error, so might be it accept only one at a time, either "data:" or "content:". Any thoughts..

Comment: That should definitely work. img-src data: content: ;

Comment: I will give a try again and will let you know. I have fixed my issue by changing the approach a little way. Previously, I was using FILE_URL, which was taking file url as "content://", so now changed it to DATA_URI which works fine on all platforms.